# Grub install. RAID

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, raid

Пытаюсь установить grub на RAID командой:

```
grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck --debug /dev/sda5
```

Лог ошибки:

```
Установка для платформы i386-pc.
<огромный лог>
grub-install: ошибка: не удалось определить файловую систему в hostdisk//dev/sda; невозможно выполнить безопасную проверку.
```

Как решить?
Система даже видит RAID как загрузочный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/6215965 читали?

Comment: да, читал. Решения не получил

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют

Comment: в свое время ставил на програмный рейд линукс и подобную проблему решил просто - boot на отдельном разделе и в raid0 режиме. В результате при загрузке испльзуется только один диск для старта, а потом оба (корневой раздел на рейд1)

Comment: в вопросе напрочь отсутствует какая-либо полезная для ответа информация — каким образом загружена система, в которой вы проделываете манипуляции, каким образом должна загружаться целевая система, где и что находится у вас на дисках. помимо перечисленного, не приведён вывод ни `fdisk -l`, ни `cat /proc/mdstat`. // в текущей редакции вопрос должен быть закрыт ввиду невозможности дать на него ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае, обычно, нужно на рутовый раздел(все разделы которые входят в массив являющийся корнем) установить тип bios_grub и потом выполнять grub_install

С помощью parted это делается так. К примеру sda1.

```
parted /dev/sda
>set 1 bios_grub on
>quit

bash#grub-install /dev/sda
```

Массив определяется по суперблокам, так что смена типа с raid на bios_grub, повлиять не должна. а вот grub без своего типа - ставиться отказывается.